# Is it possible to get the data from an HID through bluetooth in IOS platform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, hid, bluetooth-lowenergy

Our company developed a project keyboard using bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) to connect with iPhone. It is a HID and can send both keyboard and mouse data depending on the mode it is on. My job is to develop an iOS application to catch the data from it. In my last case, IOHIDLib in OS X platforms can do it easily, but in iOS platform i found that it is hard to get something similar with IOHIDLib. I have tried some ways.

1. CoreBluetooth, but this library can't communicate with HID.
2. BluetoothManager, but private framework is hard to maintain and it doesn't
   support iOS 9.3
3. Gamekit, but this is only for two IOS devices.
4. ExternalAccessory, but our product don't have a MFi license and have no plan 
   to get one.

To put it simply, what I need exactly is a way or a framework allows me to read and write data with a HID through BLE in IOS platforms.

I will appreciate any help!! :目

P.S. The project keyboard works well, I can use it to type letters on my iPhone correctly.

P.S. I use Objective-c.

Comment: HID is handled by iOS directly. Apps cannot receive HID input.  Since your device is BLE, it can use the GATT profile to send data to an app using Core Bluetooth on the iOS side, but you can't use HID over GATT; this is not an exposed to Core Bluetooth

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation!! Now we follow your suggestion to add a new service. It works right now. Thx again!